# Android TextView can't align text top

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` that doesn't align its text top and it just cuts it out, this is my xml structure:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="45dp" >

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/privacyBtn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:button="@drawable/login_checkbox" />

                    <com.test.test.TopAlignedTextView
                        android:id="@+id/privacyText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:text="Ho preso visione e acconsento al trattamento dei dati personali ai sensi dell’art. 13 d. lgs. 196/2003"
                        android:textColor="@color/lowBlack"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Where `com.test.test.TopAlignedTextView` is a class i've created in order to programmatically set the vertical alignment top, this is the code:

```
class TopAlignedTextView extends TextView {

    // Default constructor when inflating from XML file
    public TopAlignedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    // Default constructor override
    public TopAlignedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setIncludeFontPadding(false); //remove the font padding
        setGravity(getGravity() | Gravity.TOP); //make sure that the gravity is set to the top
    }

    /*This is where the magic happens*/
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        TextPaint textPaint = getPaint(); 
        textPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();
        canvas.save();

        //converts 5dip into pixels            
        int additionalPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        //subtracts the additional padding from the top of the canvas that textview draws to in order to align it with the top.            
        canvas.translate(0, -additionalPadding);
        if(getLayout() != null)
            getLayout().draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

And this is the result I get:
[image: And this is the result I get:]

The text gets cut off both from top and bottom and I have no idea on how to fix this

Comment: set custom height for textView and test it, for ex 200dp

Comment: have you tried with an xml ony approach? You should not use a custom TextView element only for setting the layout gravity.

Comment: @StackDiego Yeah I've already tried only by using xml but with no results, that's why I've tried with a custom class

Comment: I think it is happening when you do this "canvas.translate(0, -additionalPadding);"
Try not to remove additional padding

Comment: @Signo maybe there's something wrong not in the linear layout but in his father or some siblings, I copy-pasted your layout in a new blank xml file and the issue is not presenting

Comment: Can you try changing width to 0dp and add android:weight=1 ?

Comment: @LarsC Tried but it gives the same result,